# Dynamically added views not overlapping each other in relativelayout after dragged

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-relativelayout

I have a relativelayout consisting a button

**my layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#CDC2C0"
android:id="@+id/ondraglayout">

<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="T"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/mainButton1"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/xvalue"
    android:background="#E1A29D"
    android:id="@+id/edtxtlayout"/>
```

This button add text views which cand be dragged and dropped when clicked

My problem is how to prevent these textvies from overlapping each other when dragged and dropped on one another

Dynamic adding and dragging of textviews i said looks like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwrhOOD5lzWOMl9aY1ZwdmUtRlk/view?usp=drivesdk)

**my main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

RelativeLayout dropLayoutNew;

Button addText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    dropLayoutNew = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.edtxtlayout);    
    dropLayoutNew.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    addText = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainButton1);
    addText.setOnClickListener(new MyButtonClickListener());





}

}
```

** MyLongClickListner **

```
public class MyLongClickListner implements OnLongClickListener
 {

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v)
{

    ClipData dragdata = ClipData.newPlainText("","");

    View.DragShadowBuilder shdwbldr = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);

    v.startDrag(dragdata, shdwbldr, v, 0);
    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    return true;
}

   }
```

**my clicklistener**

```
public class MyButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener
 {

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    ViewGroup relativeParent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
    CustomEdittext edttxt = new CustomEdittext(v.getContext());
    relativeParent.addView(edttxt);
    edttxt.setOnLongClickListener(new MyLongClickListener());

}

  }
```

**my draglistener**

```
public class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener
 {

private LayoutParams params;

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event)
{
    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();


    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

            params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();  
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :

            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
            x=  (int) event.getX();
            y =  (int) event.getY();
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED   :

            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

            x = (int) event.getX();
            y = (int) event.getY();
            params.leftMargin = x;
            params.topMargin = y;

            view.setLayoutParams(params);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            break;
        default: break;
    }
    return true;
}


 }
```

**myButtonClickListener**

```
public class MyButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener
{

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    ViewGroup relativeParent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
      TextView txt = new TextView(v.getContext());
    relativeParent.addView(txt);
      txt.setText("Drag me");
    txt.setOnLongClickListener(new MyLongClickListner());

}

}
```